# is compare_exchange_weak for std::shared_ptr broken in msvs 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, atomic

Look at the sample, please

```
std::atomic < std::shared_ptr < int > > a;

std::shared_ptr < int > b;
std::shared_ptr < int > c = std::make_shared < int > (10);

while(a.compare_exchange_weak(b, c));

assert(a.load() == c);  
assert(a.load().use_count() == 2); // <- assertion is failed.
```

What do you think? Is it compiler error?

Build with msvs 2013 in win32 mode

Comment: There is a C++(17?) standard design proposal for atomic_shared_ptr by Herb Sutter, the document also explains the drawbacks of the existing approach: open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

> **29.5/1** There is a generic class template `atomic<T>`. The type of the template argument `T` shall be trivially copyable (3.9).

`shared_ptr<int>` is not trivially copyable.

Comment: This answer is correct till C++20. For details on how it changed in C++20 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62152248/2085626) at this page.

Answer (score 4):

Per Igor's answer, `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` does not have defined behavior. You need to use [the non-member `shared_ptr` atomic function overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) as detailed in C++11 §20.7.2.5 `shared_ptr` atomic access [util.smartptr.shared.atomic].

```
std::shared_ptr < int > a;

std::shared_ptr < int > b;
std::shared_ptr < int > c = std::make_shared < int > (10);

while(std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&a, &b, c))
  ;

assert(std::atomic_load(&a) == c);  
assert(std::atomic_load(&a).use_count() == 2);
```

It seems odd to me that the standard does not mandate a partial specialization of `template <typename T> struct std::atomic<shared_ptr<T>>` to be implemented with these functions.

I see no mention of the non-member atomic overloads in [Microsoft's documentation of the `<memory>` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k11k2x83.aspx), so they may not be implemented in VS2013.

Comment: This answer is correct till C++20. For details on how it changed in C++20 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62152248/2085626) at this page.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about C++11 but it worth pointing out that **since C++20** the OP code is valid as there is a specialization for `std::atomic` for both `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`.

See: [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2)

Also, the alternative of using `std::atomic_compare_exchange` was [deprecated in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).